# Can I define own behavior of a mock method with Minitest?

Tags: ruby, minitest

Is it possible to define own behavior of mock method using Minitest? I have found only solutions like "if called A return B", but I'd like to define own, alternative behavior in some block or lambda. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`minitest/mock` does have a [block expectation feature](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/32d49db55d80b8479237898f07d161bb52ef905c/lib/minitest/mock.rb#L84), have you tried it?